Differentiability at a point implies lipschitz of order 1 at that point.
I’m trying to prove part c of exercise 11-34 in Spivak’s Calculus book.
First, he says that a function $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha$ at $x$ if for some constant $C$ and interval around $x$:
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^\alpha.$$
To prove:

If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then it is Lipschitz of order $1$ at $x$.

My answer was basically applying the definition of differentiability (the one that looks most similar to Lipschitz definition) for a positive $\epsilon$ and then use the reverse triangle inequality to derive that on the respective $\delta$ neighborhood, the function is Lipschitz of order 1 at $x$ with Lipschitz constant $C= \epsilon +|f'(x)|$.
To be more verbose:
Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.
For some arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ there is some other number $\delta > 0$ such that if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, then
$$\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} -f'(x_0)\right\rvert<\epsilon.$$
Then using the reverse triangle inequality with this fact it follows that
$$\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\right\rvert - \left\lvert f'(x_0)\right\rvert < \epsilon$$
Thanks!

Looks good to me. Nice solution! You could also just take $\epsilon=1$ for convenience

Thank you! I wasn’t sure if I applied the inequality correctly
